# cross-compile opencv for arm : c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthumb’; did you mean ‘-mtbm’?

Tags: c++, opencv, arm, cross-compiling, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to cross-compile opencv 4.0/3.4 for a Tinker Board - ARM-based processor — the Rockchip RK3288

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 as host machine.

I pretty much followed everything mentioned [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d76/tutorial_arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html).

But when I try the cmake using below:

```
mike@mike-laptop:~/opencv-3.4.5/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/linux/arm-gnueabi.toolchain.cmake ../ I am getting the below error:

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: /usr/bin/c++ Build flags: -mthumb;;-fdata-sections;-Wa,--noexecstack;-fsigned-char;-Wno-psabi Id flags:

The output was: 1 c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthumb’; did you mean ‘-mtbm’?

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: /usr/bin/c++ Build flags: -mthumb;;-fdata-sections;-Wa,--noexecstack;-fsigned-char;-Wno-psabi Id flags: -c

The output was: 1 c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthumb’; did you mean ‘-mtbm’?
```

and tons of more messages

Comment: I succesfully reproduced your error by not having the arm compiler in my `$PATH`.
Did you install the appropriate toolchain as stated in the instructions? (`sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`). Can you confirm the installed cross-compiler is in your `$PATH` by typing `arm-` in a terminal and pressing tab to auto-complete and seeing if it suggests `arm-eabi-gcc` and the likes of it?

Answer (score 9):

I had met the same problem. I try

```
sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabi
sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

and I solve it.

I hope it will help you!